# increment / decrements number in Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, increment, decrement

I want to increment number from 1 to 50.

I try to use this code, like below, but function doesn't work.

[Demo](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ehqkjW)

In html I have :

```
            <Button text="+" (tap)="plus()"></Button>
            <Button text="-" (tap)="minus()"></Button>
```

In ts I have to function, like below:

```
 plus() {
        var first: number = 1;
        var last: number = 50;
        let num = first + 1
        console.log("Value of num1 after increment ", first)
        if (num === last) {
            console.log('disable')
        } else {
            console.log('num plus', num)
        }
    }

    minus() {
        var first1: number = 1;
        var last1: number = 50;
        let num1 = first1 - 1
        console.log("Value of num1 after decr ", first1)
        if (num1 === last1) {
            console.log('disable')
        } else {
            console.log('num minus', num1)
        }
    }
```

Any idea please, how to increment/ decrements number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your variables outside `plus()` and `minus()` methods. The `first` and `last` numbers are not changeable I guess.

**app.component.ts:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  last1 = 50;
  last2 = -50;
  num1 = 0;
  num2 = 0;

  plus() {
    if (this.num1 === this.last1) {
      console.log("disable");
    } else {
      this.num1++;
      console.log("Value of num1 after increment ", this.num1);
    }
  }
  minus() {
    if (this.num2 === this.last2) {
      console.log("disable");
    } else {
      this.num2--;
      console.log("Value of num1 after decr ", this.num2);
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<Button (click)="plus()" class="btn">+</Button>
<Button (click)="minus()" class="btn">-</Button>

<p>Num1: {{num1}}</p>
<p>Num2: {{num2}}</p>
```

Comment: I try it, but nothing change. Please, can you see demo? Thank you!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1a9pw?file=src/app/app.component.html